# Objectify4 query a list attribute with a list condition

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, objectify

I have an object called **Guy** which has an attribute **girlfriends** type Key[]

Given a list of Longs which are the Girl's ids I want to query **all the Guy's which have any of these girls as girlfriend.**

For **example** *(Guy: gilfriends)*:

```
 LuckyGuy: {a,b,c}
 Guy1: {b}
 Guy2: {c}
```

I want *g* such as:

```
 g({a,b}) = LuckyGuy, Guy1
 g({c})) = LuckyGuy, Guy2
```

I could make a loop:

```
for(i..n)
    resultSet.add(
        objectifyFactory.begin().load().type(User.class).filter("girlfriends", girlfriendId[i])
    );
```

But I'm sure there is a direct strategy.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datastore does not support 'or' queries. You will need to query for each of the 'girlfriend' IDs separately, and combine the result sets.